# Paper in Calculus of Variation: Question on why $\;\inf \{ E_1(u)\}\;$ can't be less than $\;\min \{E_1(u)\}\;$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum

I'm reading a paper in Calculus of Variation and I've been stuck to the proof of the following Corollary. But first let me introduce the problem:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

*NOTE:* There is a typo in the proof of Corollary 3.2. There is no Lemma 3.2 in the paper. **It means the lower bound in the statement of Corollary 3.2.**

**What I cannot see that easy is why $\;\inf \{E_1(u):u\in S(a,b),d_1(u,\mathcal Z) \ge \beta\} \lt e_1\;$ is impossible  and hence the proof is complete after contradicting only the case of equality with $\;e_1\;$**. I do understand that in case the equality holds , we lead to a contradiction but I don't see why the writer doesn't examine also the case in which $\;\inf \{E_1(u):u\in S(a,b),d_1(u,\mathcal Z) \ge \beta\} \lt e_1\;$..

Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your definition of the minimzer $e_1$ by:
\begin{align}
e_1 = \min\{ E_1(v): v \in S(a,b) \}
\end{align}
Now if your assume that in the above corollar the equality holds than, by the property of the infimum you can find a sequence $u_n$ so that:
\begin{align}
E_1(u_n) \longrightarrow e_1 = E_1(z) \quad (n \rightarrow \infty) \text{ and $d(u_n,z) \geq \beta$ for some $z \in \mathcal{Z}$   } 
\end{align}
If you find a sequence $x_n$, which converges pointwise to $z$ then the distance to $\mathcal{Z}$ tends especially to zero, because we have taken $z \in \mathcal{Z}$.

Comment: excuse me if I'm missing something, but I don't see how this answers my question...Why $\;\inf \{ E_1(u):u\in S(a,b),d_1(u,\mathcal Z) \le \beta\} \lt e_1\;$ is impossible? could you give me more details?

Comment: You defined the value $e_1$ as the minimum off all minimizers. This implies that the infimum of the subset, with aditional property $d_1(u,\mathcal{Z})\geq \beta$ can not be smaller than $e_1$.

Comment: I'm so silly. Of course, thanks